# How can I move task items beyond the initial columns using react beautiful dnd?

Tags: reactjs

I have 3 columns to hold tasks the user types in. I can move and reorder tasks within the To-Do column but cannot move items between columns and have their order saved. I have been messing with the `onDrageEnd` function but can't seem to get it to work. I basically want a user to be able to drag tasks across all columns and reorder tasks in all columns.

Here is my App.js file that has the onDragEnd function:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Column from "./Column";
import Note from "./Note";
import { DragDropContext } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function App() {
  const [taskText, setTaskText] = useState("");
  const [notes, setNote] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setTaskText(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick(event) {
    setNote((prevNotes) => {
      return [...prevNotes, taskText];
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  function displayNotes() {
    return notes.map((note, index) => {
      return (
        <Note key={index} id={uuidv4()} noteContent={note} index={index} />
      );
    });
  }


  function handleOnDragEnd(result){

    const newNotesArray = Array.from(notes);
    const [reorderedItem] = newNotesArray.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    newNotesArray.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
    if(!result.destination) return;
    setNote(newNotesArray);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <p>Add a Task</p>
        <input type="text" value={taskText} onChange={handleChange} />
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Add</button>
      </form>
      <div className="container">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
        <Column
        dropId={uuidv4()}
        text="To-Do"
          showNotes={displayNotes()}
        />
        <Column
        dropId={uuidv4()} 
        text="In Progress"
        />
        <Column
        dropId={uuidv4()} 
        text="Done"/>
      </DragDropContext>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is the Note.JSX file that contains the note(task) the user creates:

```
import React from "react";
import { Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

function Note(props) {
  return (
    <Draggable draggableId={props.id} index={props.index}>
      {(provided) => (
        <div
          className="note"
          ref={provided.innerRef}
          {...provided.draggableProps}
          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
        >
          <p>{props.noteContent}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </Draggable>
  );
}

export default Note;
```

Here is the Column.jsx file that contains the column that holds the tasks:

```
import React from "react";
import { Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

function Column(props) {
  return (
    <Droppable droppableId={props.dropId}>
      {(provided) => (
          <div
            className="taskColumn"
            {...provided.droppableProps}
            ref={provided.innerRef}
          >
            <p>{props.text}</p>
            <p>{props.showNotes}</p>
            {provided.placeHolder}
          </div>
      )}
    </Droppable>
  );
}

export default Column;
```

My main focus has been messing around with the onDragEnd function in the App.js file:

```
function handleOnDragEnd(result){

    const newNotesArray = Array.from(notes);
    const [reorderedItem] = newNotesArray.splice(result.source.index, 1);
    newNotesArray.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
    if(!result.destination) return;
    setNote(newNotesArray);
  }
```

Update:
I have watched the video but am still having issues. Below is my new `onDragEnd` function.

```
function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
    const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;
    const start = source.droppableId;
    const finish = destination.droppableId;

    //If moviing to no appropriate column
    if (!destination) return;

    //If moving within same column
    if (start === finish) {
      const newNotesArray = Array.from(notes);
      const [reorderedItem] = newNotesArray.splice(result.source.index, 1);

      newNotesArray.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);

      setNote(newNotesArray);
    }

    //Moving between columns

    if (start !== finish) {
      const betweenColumnsArray = Array.from(notes);
      betweenColumnsArray.splice(source.index, 1);
      const newStart = {
        ...start,
        betweenColumnsArray
      };

      const finishArray = Array.from(finish);
      finishArray.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);
      const newFinish = {
        ...finish,
        finishArray
      };

      setNote(betweenColumnsArray);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now the moving of items between columns is pretty complex, I could show you the whole process here.

But I think it will be easier for you if you check this tutorial out, that shows exactly what you need
https://egghead.io/lessons/react-move-items-between-columns-with-react-beautiful-dnd-using-ondragend

It's a free course on React Beautiful DnD, you may have to create an account though.

Comment: I have watched the video but am still having some issues. I didn't start with predefined task data so it's difficult for me to follow the video exactly. Here's the link to the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-morning-po7hr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Here is the fully working example from the tutorial
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-shape-v0j69?file=/src/App.js

I tried editing your sandbox, but I didn't fully understand what you're trying to do. Hope this fully working example will help you. You can ask me any questions about this one